# I changed the SelectedItem via a Binding. Now how do I move it into view without code-behind?

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I've got a DataGrid with a Two-Way Binding on SelectedItem.  I can change the SelectedItem in my ViewModel, but the DataGrid won't ScrollIntoView automatically.

Is there a way to do this without using a code-behind event handler that calls `ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem)`, or should I just give in and use a little code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/125583/ScrollIntoView-for-a-DataGrid-when-using-MVVM.aspx